# How to make vim search every time I add a new character to the search?

Tags: search

When I use `sublime text` I find that it starts searching every time I press a key in the search, i.e. every time I add another letter to the search`sublime` performs the search and shows a match with all that I typed.

In vim once I type <kbd>/</kbd> and input a search I need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> for the search to be performed.

Is there a way to have `vim` with a similar behavior to `sublime`?

Comment: You can press / in normal mode and then type the text/pattern to search. You want more simplified than this?

Comment: You mean, autocompletion? Please describe the behavior, don't assume Vim users know about Sublime-anything :)

Comment: Yes, immediately when I pressed key on keyboard make search, but keep my cursor in command panel and when I push ENTER move cursor into text area

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to highlight matches as you search, you need to `set incsearch`.  Read `:help 'incsearch'` for full details.

`incsearch` will scroll to the first match.  Pressing `<esc>` while searching will cancel and restore the scroll position.  Pressing `<enter>` will move the cursor to the first match.

You can change the incremental search highlight using the `IncSearch` highlight group.

There is also a plugin called [incsearch.vim](https://github.com/haya14busa/incsearch.vim) that will highlight all matches as you type, in addition to other features.

Comment: Also, there is the incsearch plugin. One of my absolute favorites, absolutely recommend it!

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Thanks, that does look like a great plugin!  I updated the answer with a link.

Comment: Should you not also include [this link](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5038)?

Comment: @Tumbler41 Nah. vim.org's script listings tend to be less informative if the plugin is hosted on GitHub. Besides, the more informative GitHub page has a link to vim.org. With the inability to format text or add images, linking to vim.org/scripts is a good way to not impress someone relatively new to Vim, IMO.